# How to place one column value in two columns in mysql

Tags: mysql

There is a situation

There is a competition. I have a table of all participants.

```
id   name
1    ali
2    naeem
3    waleed
4    aqeel
```

Now I have to set competition between two participants. Table structure is like that

```
id   first_parti_id    second_parti_id
1           1                 4
2           2                 3
```

Now i want to display their details in a table like

```
first         vs        second
ali                     aqeel
naeem                   waleed
```

But i am unable to write query which extract data from participants table. 
Thanks a lot for this wonderful platform

Comment: Use a JOIN with table aliases so you can join to the participant table twice

Comment: This query works great, if i have only one record in table

Comment: <pre>SELECT (SELECT C.comp_id FROM compitation C ) AS comp_id, (SELECT C.status FROM compitation C ) AS status, (SELECT C.present FROM compitation C ) AS present, (SELECT P.parti_name FROM participents P INNER JOIN compitation C ON P.parti_id = C.first_parti_id) AS first_name, (SELECT P.parti_name FROM participents P INNER JOIN compitation C ON P.parti_id = C.second_parti_id) AS second_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `participants` table twice, using two different aliases for example `p1` and `p2`:

```
SELECT
  p1.name AS first,
  p2.name AS second
FROM
  competition INNER JOIN participants p1
  ON competition.first_parti_id = p1.id
  INNER JOIN participants p2
  ON competition.second_parti_id = p2.id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped a lot. But if i want to get all fields  competition table as well.. then what i have to do?

Comment: @user2782577 you could use `SELECT competition.*, p1.name AS first, p2.name AS second FROM ...`